# How can I find a water leak in the bottom right side of my civic trunk?

Tags: honda, civic, leak, water-leak, trunk

Somehow water is getting inside of my trunk on my 2010 Honda Civic LX. It is the right hand side underneath the molded carpeting. Specifically, if you take the plastic clips out on the left-hand side of the trunk to access the rear lights of the car. After separating those clips and peeling back the molded carpeting and looking down, you can see the innards of the body of the car behind the wheel well.

[image: Inside of left side of trunk under molded carpeting]

As you can see by the picture, it is below the air pressure equalization flaps (the black piece in the upper left corner of the photo) that are behind the bumper. First, I thought the water was coming in through those flaps when I was driving the car because the water was getting kicked up underneath there but I have not driven my car today and it is raining and now there is water pooling in there again so the leak is coming from another place.

Any ideas how to find the leak? This is been going on for months and I’m concerned about mold if this continues to happen over time.